# CopyQ global shortcut not working on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04, clipboard-manager

CopyQ clipboard manager global shortcut to show/hide main window does not work on Ubuntu 21.04 (doesn't work under Wayland windows manager)

Answer (score 23):

Workaround is assigning a shortcut in Gnome

Open Setting from the top bar, select keyboard shortcuts

Scroll to the bottom and hit "+"

Enter the name of your choice, type `copyq -e "toggle()"`in the Command field

Hit Set Shortcut and press your favorite keys.

Comment: Is there any advice how to make copyq window focused and bring it to the front after the hotkey is pressed, when using this workaround? Otherwise it opens but stays behind the current windows.

Comment: The command 'copyq toggle' is enough btw.

Answer (score 9):

Just like the top answer by @quinta, set the Gnome Settings Custom Keyboard shortcuts which take precedence on a Ubuntu desktop system. However instead of opening the main window with `copyq toggle`, we will use a different command to open its menu. I think its more streamlined to open copyqs menu as its more compact.

1. Open Setting from the top bar, select keyboard shortcuts
2. Scroll to the bottom and hit "+"
3. Set the command instead to `copyq menu`
4. Hit Set Shortcut and press your favorite keys.

From the menu, you can use the arrow keys and hit enter to open the Main Window

Answer (score 3):

To have the CopyQ window focused using the workaround suggested by quinta, try checking "Always on top" in CopyQ settings, General.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to consider would be to choose "Ubuntu on XOrg" in the login screen and keep using XOrg for a bit more until remaining Wayland issues are ironed out, hopefully in the next release.

(Click on the gear icon in the bottom right corner of the login screen. If it is not there, go to the password prompt step.)